# Group/lab guide for new students and post-docs: what should it contain?

Tags: management

Large research groups have guides for newcomers, which contain both important information, both high-level and practical, on their new position and the group. I don't have such a large group, but I can see the value in keeping all important information in one central place.

So, if I get to writing such a document, what information should one put in a group guide for new group members?

Comment: Does this group include international students and post-docs?

Comment: @FaheemMitha yes, it's international

Comment: I hate bureaucracy, but I would start off by talking to HR to make sure you include everything you "have" to. This probably can be a page of links to relevant web pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find a lot of good examples on the web, written by professors with a lot more experience, but [here is mine](http://www.davidketcheson.info/guidelines.pdf).  It includes guidelines and advice on:

- How to approach group meetings and individual meetings with advisor (me)
- Finding a thesis topic
- Planning and recording research
- Reading the literature
- Writing papers
- Publishing papers
- Giving talks
- Programming
- Recommended software tools
- General conduct

Comment: Your guide was very enlightening, and very well organized (which I am sure reflects the state of your lab). Thank you!